# cin.get() error

Tags: c++, input

I'm fairly new to C++ and in need of some understanding for the function cin.get(). I wrote this function and I'm getting an error on this line

```
string getName(string& name){
    cout<<"Enter your full name: ";
    cin.get(cin,name);      //this line
    return name; 
}
```

Specifically, I am getting an error on the `.`, the error stating:

> no instance of overloaded function

Comment: Hint: Why won't you just use `cin >> name;` or `getline(cin, name)`?

Comment: I forgot to add that I am trying to input a full name as in first and last, with a space in between. However I will try the "getline()"

Comment: Right. I've given the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line:

```
cin.get(cin,name);
```

with this:

```
cin >> name
```

Edit: According to your latest comment to deal with with spaces you can use this:

```
cin >> skipws >> name;
```

Comment: Forget what I said. Use `skipws`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a c-style string to `get` the name-lastname first:

```
string getName(string& name){
  char str[256];
  cout<<"Enter your full name: ";
  cin.get(str, sizeof(str));
  return name = str; 
}
```